# Drupal: Easy Views issue I just can't figure out

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I think this issue is easy to figure out, but I'm just not getting it because I'm relatively new to Drupal.  I'm trying to create something similar to the Game News section on NCSoft's site http://us.ncsoft.com/en/ where the title, then summary of the body of the story is on one side and the icon for that game is on the left.

I could easily create a content type that has an image field in it and then upload the appropriate icon for each story, each time.  A better solution would be to create a field in the Game_News content type called "Game_News_Subject" and write an override tpl file to display the proper logo depending on which game the story is about.  But, if possible, I'd like to create two different content types: One that has the basic article stuff and what game the article is about and a second content type that has the subject the game is about and the logo that goes with it.

That way, anytime I needed to add or change a logo, I could just deal with the Game_Logo content type.  And anytime I, or any other manager of my site, wanted to write an article about a game all we'd need to do was hit "Add Content > Select 'Game_News_Store' > Write the article > Select from radio buttons what game the article is about > Enter" and boom, the article appeard on our front page just like the articles on the NCSoft page shows up.

I've been stuck on this for months.  I'd really appreciate very detailed information on how to solve this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would using a taxonomy tag for each game be a possibility? You can add an image field to the tag, then use Relationships in the view to attach the tag to the view. This allows you to access the tag's image field through the normal view fields.

Another advantage to this approach would be that it automatically creates a page that displays all the news for each game. You could also use the description field on the tag to display the game's info on this page.

Comment: Holy crap, that worked.  I had the Taxonomy module installed, but I didn't really know what it did.  I created a Taxonomy category called "Games," and was a little weirded out that it gave me the ability to add an image field in the Taxonomy content type for "Games."  So I added the logo images to each Taxonomy term, and in Views, created a Relationship for the Taxonomy "Games" type, then added to "Views:Game News" the image field in the Taxonomy for it, and it worked.

Thanks Will.